Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'
I'm trying to retrieve all order data by using repeater.
Therefore, I face this problem but I never happen this kind of error before since it can work as usual.
My code:
protected void OrderRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        //Assign status to page variable
        status = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblStatus");


        // Get the current order's data
        **DataRowView orderData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;**
        int orderID = orderData.Row.Field<int>("OrderID");

        // Filter the DataTable to get items for the current order
        DataTable itemsForOrder = ((DataView)TrackingSource.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty))
            .Table
            .Select($"OrderID= {orderID}")
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Field<DateTime>("OrderDate"))
            .CopyToDataTable();
        itemsForOrder.DefaultView.Sort = "OrderDate DESC";

        CalculateEstimatedShippingDate(e.Item);
    }
    else
    {
        lblFail.Text = "You have no purchased records.";
    }
}

Source error:
DataRowView orderData = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

For my opinion is it may have some bug during the complilation since I'm using Visual Studio 2022. It may close the entire windows and open it again. So it can run as usual. This is my expectation. Thank you.

How EXACTLY did you bind the data in the first place?

@jmcilhinney
At front end I use SQLDataSource and backend I use a method called private DataTable GetDataFromDatabase(string custID).

No one should need to read the comments to understand the question. You need to edit your question and provide all the relevant information.

var orderID  =((YOUR CLASS_NAME)e.Item.DataItem).OrderID

I should point out that ONLY during the databinding events, is the data source item (row) available. This of course means that even columns not included in the markup (in this case a repeater) can be freely used and obtained. However, once databinding is complete, then the data item (row item) goes out of scope.
So, keep in mind, for above to work, then the data you feed to the GridView, ListView, or in this case the Repeater must be an IEnumerable list of data.
That means while the Repeater, ListView etc. will work if you feed the control with a reader, but will NOT work if you attempt to obtain the data row used for binding.
So, take this simple repeater:
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
        OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <h4 id="myH3" runat="server"><%# Eval("HotelName") %> </h4>
            <br />
            <hr />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>

And code behind to load up this repeater:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadData();
    }

    void LoadData()
    {

        string strSQL = 
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
             ORDER BY HotelName";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                Repeater1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
                Repeater1.DataBind();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        // if active column = true, highligt in blue

        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            DataRowView MyDataRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

            if ((bool)MyDataRow["Active"] == true)
            {

                HtmlGenericControl H3 = (HtmlGenericControl)e.Item.FindControl("myH3");
                H3.Style.Add("background-color", "skyblue");


            }
        }
    }

Now, the above code would work if we do NOT attempt to use:
   DataRowView MyDataRow = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;

So, for the e.Item.DataItem to be legal, then the data source of the control has to be IEnumerable, and a reader is not. So, can you bind a GridView, Repeater etc. with a data source that is not IEnumerable such as a data repeater?
Yes, you can! But, if that will not allow use of e.Item.DataItem.
So, for above code to work, we have to feed the data bound control a IEnumerable list.
Hence, this code will now work:
    void LoadData()
    {

        string strSQL = 
            @"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA
             ORDER BY HotelName";

        DataTable dtHotels = new DataTable();

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                dtHotels.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());  
            }
        }

        Repeater1.DataSource = dtHotels;
        Repeater1.DataBind();

    }

And the result is thus now this:

So, the first code example will work if we do NOT use the e.Item.DataItem, since you can feed such data aware controls a data reader (that is a forward only data source).
However, when using e.Item.DataItem, then the data source can't be a "reader", since it does not result in a IEnumerable list - one that allows repeated use of each row, not a reader row by row that once used goes out of scope.
You don't show your code to load up the Repeater's data source, but a common issue is feeding the data control a reader works, but it does not work if you attempt to use e.Item.DataItem in the row data bound event.
Show your code used to load up that Repeater, I'm guessing you are feeding that data control a data reader, which as pointed out can be used, but does not allow use of the row binding source in the row data binding event.
